# Collision detection only works when object hits right in the centre

Tags: java, processing

Hi so i have here a 'falling' style game where i have homer simpsons head falling through the sky avoiding the salads and collecting burgers to increase score. I have implemented collision detection so when homer hits a salad he should re-spawn and have a life deducted which works fine. However if homers head hits the side of the salad and not directly in the centre of it the game will freeze for a moment and then carry on like nothing happened. I am not sure why this happens and wondering if there is a problem with how i am doing this. Here is my code below:

Are the collision detection not accurate enough or is there another issue that i am missing?

```
PImage background;
PImage MenuBackground;
int y=0;//global variable background location
final int End = 0;
final int Active = 1;
final int Menu = 2;
int gameMode = Menu;
int score = 0;
int lives = 3;
Boolean BurgerCollisionInProgress = false;
Boolean BurgerCollisionInProgress2 = false;


Salad salad1;
Salad salad2;
Salad salad3;
Homer user1;
Burger Burger;


public void settings()
{
 size(500,1000); //setup size of canvas
}

void menu()
{
 background = loadImage("spaceBackground.jpg"); //image used for background
 background.resize(500,1000); //resizes the background
 gameMode = Active; 

float rand = random(25,475);
int intRand = int(rand);

float rand2 = random(25,475);
int intRand2 = int(rand2); 

float rand3 = random(25,475);
int intRand3 = int(rand3); 

float rand4 = random(25,475);
int intRand4 = int(rand4); 


 user1 = new Homer(250,100);  //declares new defender as user1
 Burger = new Burger(intRand,900,2);
 salad1 = new Salad(intRand2,900,3);
 salad2 = new Salad(intRand3,900,3);
 salad3 = new Salad(intRand4,900,3); //3 aliens declared with their x and y position and their speed they move at
 draw();
}


void setup()
{
  if(gameMode == 2)
  {    
    MenuBackground = loadImage("simpMenu.png");
    MenuBackground.resize(540,1000);
    image(MenuBackground, 0, y);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textSize(40);
    fill(252, 3, 3);
    text("Press 'p' to play", 250,500);     
  } 
}


void draw ()
{  
  if (gameMode == Active)
  {        
    if(crash() == false)
    {
      drawBackground();//calls the drawBackground method
      textSize(32);
      fill(22,100,8);
      text("Score: " + score,75,40); 
      text("Lives: " + lives,75,80);
      salad1.update();//calls the update method which holds the move and render methods for alien
      salad2.update();
      salad3.update();
      user1.render();//calls the update method which holds the move and render methods for user
      Burger.update();//calls the update method which holds the move and render methods for burger

      if(Bcrash() == true && BurgerCollisionInProgress == false)
      {
      score = score+1;
      BurgerCollisionInProgress = true;
      Burger.y = 900;
      float rand = random(25,475);
      int intRand = int(rand);
      Burger.x = intRand;
      }

      if(Bcrash() == false)
      {
      BurgerCollisionInProgress = false;
      }


      if(crash() == true && BurgerCollisionInProgress2 == false)
      {
        if (lives < 1)
        {   gameMode = End;
            textSize(28);
            fill(22,100,8);
            text("Game Over, press 'r' to restart",200,200);
        }
        else
        {
          lives = lives - 1;
          BurgerCollisionInProgress2 = true;
          menu();
        }
        if(crash() == false)
      {
      BurgerCollisionInProgress2 = false;
      }
     }      
    }
  }
}

void drawBackground()
{
 image(background, 0, y); //draw background twice adjacent
 image(background, 0, y-background.width);
 y -=2;
 if(y == -background.width)
 y=0; //wrap background
}


  boolean crash()
  {
    if(user1.crash(salad1))
    {
      return true;
    }
    if(user1.crash(salad2))
    {
      return true;
    }
    if(user1.crash(salad3))
    {     
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


  boolean Bcrash()
  {
    if(user1.crash(Burger))
    {      
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Homer class:

```
class Homer
{
  PImage UserImage;
  int x,y;  //declaring variables

  Homer(int x, int y)
  {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   UserImage = loadImage("homer.png");
   UserImage.resize (60, 52);   
  } // end of Homer

  void render()
  {
    //draw a Homer
 image(UserImage,x,y);

  } //end of void render

  boolean crash(Salad A)  
  {   
    if((abs(x-A.x)<=30) && abs(y-A.y)<=30)
    {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
  }// end of crash


  boolean crash(Burger A)
  {
    if((abs(x-A.x)<=30) && abs(y-A.y)<=30)
    {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
} // end of class
```

Burger Class:

```
class Burger
{
  PImage burgerImage;
  int x,y, speedX;
  int speedY = 0;

  Burger(int x, int y, int speedY)
  {     
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedY= speedY;
    burgerImage = loadImage("food.png");
    burgerImage.resize (60, 52);    
  }  

  void render()
  {
    image(burgerImage,x,y);
  }


   void move()
 {
  y = y - speedY;  
  float rand = random(25,475);
  int intRand = int(rand);
   if(this.y < 0)
   {
    this.y = 900;
    this.x = intRand;
   }  
}

void update()
{
 move();
 render();
}
 }
```

Salad Class:

```
class Salad
{
 float x,y;
 float speedX, speedY; //declaring variables
 PImage saladImage;

 Salad(int x, int y, int speedY)
 {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.speedY = speedY;
  saladImage = loadImage("salad.png");
  saladImage.resize (60, 52);  
 } //end of salad

 void move()
 {
   y=y-speedY;
   float stepY = random(-5,5);
   y = y + (int)stepY;

   float rand = random(25,475);
   int intRand = int(rand);   

   if(this.y < 0)
   {
    this.y = 900; // once the salads y is less than 0 they restart at 900
    this.x = intRand;
    speedY = speedY + 0.5;
   }
 } //end of void move

 //draw a salad
 void render()
 {
image(saladImage,x,y);

 } //end of void render 

 void update()
 {
  move();
  render();
 }
}// end of alien class
```

Comment: Are you doing this as a personal project or for homework? I would like to know if you can use Inheritance, and if so if you are willing to.

Comment: This is an assignment i am more than willing to use inheritance but how would i go about it

Comment: I'll come back to this this evening, if nobody answered in an appropriate manner before I'll explain Inheritance and basic collisions so you can use them for this project (which I still think looks very fun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several little things which makes this harder than it could be. First, your intersect method isn't quite right. Then, the way you handle coordinates could be improved upon.

What I'm going to do first is to show you how to intersect rectangles. After that, I'll show you how I would deal with the drawable objets so they stay easy to manipulate. Then I'll show you some skeleton code for a short, easy game with stuff falling and colliding, and just for you I'll add some help so you can implement these suggestions into the context of your game.

---

---

### 1. Collisions

There are many ways to handle collisions. Most of them are applied mathematics, some of them are clever algorithms making use of colors or invisible sprites. There are probably methods I'm forgetting, too.

We'll only do collisions between rectangles, as your program seems quite rectangle-friendly and it's the easier method. So we'll write a intersection detection algorithm.

First thing to do when writing an algorithm is the pseudocode. I'm not joking. It's easy to go all clakety-clak with your keyboard and hit compile. It works most of the time... but it's more intuitive logic than applying your brain to the problem.

Being able to pseudocode is like a superpower for programmers. Never underestimate it.

Now, how do you know if two rectangles are intersecting? The answer is:

1. There are 4 ways that two rectangles can intersect, whether horizontally or vertically.
2. They must intersect both horizontally and vertically to overlap for real.

These are the possibilities you have to look for:

[image: 4 ways two rectangles may intersect]

1. Red rectangle is bigger than black rectangle and black rectangle is completely inside it.
2. Both rectangles overlap on the left side (horizontally) or on the top side (vertically).
3. Red rectangle small enough to be inside black rectangle.
4. Both rectangles overlap on the right side (horizontally) or on the bottom side (vertically).

Because this code can be used in many places, I took it out of context and put it inside a fonction which takes coordinates and returns a boolean (true if there indeed is a collision):

```
//  INTERSECT RECTs
boolean intersect(float x1, float y1, float w1, float h1, float x2, float y2, float w2, float h2)
{
    boolean checkX = x1 < x2 && x1+w1 > x2 || x1 < x2+w2 && x1+w1 > x2+w2 || x1 > x2 && x1+w1 < x2+w2 || x1 < x2 && x1+w1 > x2+w2; 
    boolean checkY = y1 < y2 && y1+h1 > y2 || y1 < y2+h2 && y1+h1 > y2+h2 || y1 > y2 && y1+h1 < y2+h2 || y1 < y2 && y1+h1 > y2+h2;

    return checkX && checkY;
}
```

This is one way of handling collisions between rectangles. You could take this information and apply it to your game, and it would rock.

This said, you could also improve on your code with Inheritance...

---

---

### 2. Inheritance (in this case: for graphical objects)

Inheritance in computer science is a way to make a class obtain the properties of another one. Most people explains it in term of family: there is a parent class and there are children class which inherits the parent class' properties.

Inheritance is especially useful when several of your class share the same properties or methods. Drawable objects are a great example, because they all need coordinates. They all need a method to be drawn.

As you'll see with the example game later, I noticed that all my rectangles needed these modal variables:

```
protected float x, y, w, h; // x and y coordinate, width and height of the square
protected color fill, stroke;
protected float strokeWeight = 1;
```

So I created a base class named 'Drawable'. In a bigger project, it could be the base class of a whole tree of classes, like this:

[image: Inheritance!]

So in this example, Rat would be the child of Walker, which is the child of Enemy, which is the child of Actor, which is the child of Drawable.

The advantage is that every child inherits everything from it's parent. It both makes you write less code and let you fix your mistakes in only one place instead of everywhere. For an example, if there's a mistake in how you use the coordinates of your objects, you want to fix it in the class where this logic is written, not *in every class*.

There are many other advantages to Inheritance, but for now let's keep it simple, all right?

---

---

### 3. Example program

This one is very straightforward: this is an example which use both inheritance and collisions. You can copy and paste it into a Processing IDE and it'll run. Take some time to see how the 3 classes relate to one another, and how every child class has the modal variables and functions of it's parent.

```
Hero hero;
ArrayList<Bomb> bombs = new ArrayList<Bomb>();
int numberOfBombs = 20; // if you change this number the number of bombs will change too. Try it!
int hitCount = 0;

public void settings()
{
  size(800, 600); //setup size of canvas
}

public void setup() {
  hero = new Hero();

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBombs; i++) {
    bombs.add(new Bomb(random(20, width-20), random(1, 10)));
  }

  // This part serves no purpose but to demonstrate that you can gather objets which share a parent class together
  ArrayList<Drawable> myDrawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
  for (Bomb b : bombs) {
    myDrawables.add(b);
  }
  myDrawables.add(hero);

  for (Drawable d : myDrawables) {
    d.Render();
    // Even though hero and the bombs are different classes, they are in the same ArrayList because they share the Drawable parent class.
    // Drawable has the Render() function, which may be called, but the child class will overshadow the Drawable's method.
    // Proof is that the error message "Drawable child: Render() was not overshadowed." will not appear in the console.
  }
}


public void draw() {
  DrawBackground();

  hero.Update();
  hero.Render();

  for (Bomb b : bombs) {
    b.Update();
    b.Render();
  }

  ShowHitCount();
}


public void DrawBackground() {
  fill(0);
  stroke(0);
  rect(0, 0, width, height, 0); // dark background 
}

public void ShowHitCount() {
  textAlign (RIGHT);
  textSize(height/20);
  fill(color(200, 200, 0));
  text(hitCount, width-20, height/20 + 20);
}


class Drawable {
  protected float x, y, w, h; // 'protected' is like 'private', but child class retain access
  protected color fill, stroke;
  protected float strokeWeight = 1;

  Drawable() {
    this(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  Drawable(float x, float y, float w, float h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }

  public void Render() { print("Drawable child: Render() was not overshadowed."); } // nothing to see here: this exists so we can overshadow it in the childs
  public void Update() { print("Drawable child: Update() was not overshadowed."); } // same thing
}


class Hero extends Drawable { // 'extends' is keyword for 'will inherit from'
  Hero() {
    // 'super()' calls the parent's constructor
    // in this example, I decided that the hero would be a red 40x60 rectangle that follows the mouse X position
    super(mouseX - 20, height - 80, 40, 60);

    fill = color(200, 0, 0);
    stroke = color(250);
  }

  public void Update() { // when both parents and child have the same function (type and signature), the child's one prevail. That's overshadowing.
    x = mouseX - w/2;
  }

  public void Render() {
    fill(fill);
    stroke(stroke);
    strokeWeight(strokeWeight);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }
}


class Bomb extends Drawable {
  protected float fallSpeed;

  Bomb(float xPosition, float fallSpeed) {
    // Bombs will be small blue squares falling from the sky
    super(xPosition, -20, 20, 20);
    this.fallSpeed = fallSpeed;

    fill = color(0, 0, 200);
    stroke = fill;
  }

  private void FallAgain() {
    x = random(20, width-20);
    fallSpeed = random(1, 10);
    y = 0 - random(20, 100);
  }

  public void Update() {
    y += fallSpeed;

    // check for collision with the Hero
    if (intersect(x, y, w, h, hero.x, hero.y, hero.w, hero.h)) {
      hitCount++;
      FallAgain();
    }

    // check if it fell lower than the screen
    if (y > height) {
      FallAgain();
    }
  }

  public void Render() {
    fill(fill);
    stroke(stroke);
    strokeWeight(strokeWeight);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }
}


//  INTERSECT RECTs
boolean intersect(float x1, float y1, float w1, float h1, float x2, float y2, float w2, float h2)
{
    boolean checkX = x1 < x2 && x1+w1 > x2 || x1 < x2+w2 && x1+w1 > x2+w2 || x1 > x2 && x1+w1 < x2+w2 || x1 < x2 && x1+w1 > x2+w2; 
    boolean checkY = y1 < y2 && y1+h1 > y2 || y1 < y2+h2 && y1+h1 > y2+h2 || y1 > y2 && y1+h1 < y2+h2 || x1 < y2 && y1+h1 > y2+h2;

    return checkX && checkY;
}
```

---

---

### 4. Bonus: help with implementation

So... you're seeing this and it makes you want to improve on your program. That's good. Maybe you want to implement some inheritance, maybe just the collisions. Both can be tricky, and neither is supposed to impact the user.

This is what is called 'refactoring'.

Let's implement a Drawable class first. The rest will be easier then.

First step: find what's the common ground with Burger, Homer and Salad. From the code you posted, I can see that they need these things:

```
int x, y;
int speedX, speedY;
PImage img;
// To which I would add:
int w, h;
boolean isVisible;
```

I notice that you're using integers. That's fine, but I strongly suggest using float for coordinates. I did the same thing when I was learning to code and I ended up regretting not using float earlier. Both integer and float will probably do the trick for this project (with some cast when needed).

Also, here are a couple functions that they share:

```
void Render()
void Update()
void Move()
// To which I would add:
void SetPosition()
void SetIsVisible()
boolean Crash() // so we can check if it intersect with given coordinates
```

So far, your Drawable class could look like this:

```
class Drawable {
  public float x, y, w, h; // Making variables public while you could avoid it is bad practice, I'm doing it to avoid writing Get functions. Avoid doing this as much as possible, but bear with me for now.
  protected float speedX, speedY;
  protected PImage img;
  protected boolean isVisible = true;

  Drawable(float x, float y, float w, float h, String imagePath) {
    this.x = x; // starting x position
    this.y = y; // starting y position
    this.w = w; // width if the object (your image in this case)
    this.h = h; // height of the object (height of your image)

    if (imagePath.length() > 0) { // if there is nothing in the string it won't try to load an image
      img = loadImage(imagePath);
    }
  }

  public void Render() {
    if (isVisible && img != null) {
      image(img, x, y);
    }
  }

  public void Update() {
    Move(); // I kept Move() out of Update() so you can overshadow Update() without having to re-code Move() later
  }

  protected void Move() {
    // The 'normal' behavior of a Drawable would then to move according to it's speed.
    // You can then change how they move by changing their speed values.
    // Or... you can overshadow this function in a child class and write your own!
    x += speedX;
    y += speedY;
  }

  public void SetPosition(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public void SetIsVisible(boolean isVisible) {
    this.isVisible = isVisible;
  }

  public boolean Crash(float x, float y, float w, float h) {
    // this function uses the 'intersect' function I wrote earlier, so it would have to be included in the project
    return intersect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h, x, y, w, h);
  }
}
```

Not so bad so far, isn't it? This will make a strong base for all your objects. Now, let's see how to implement this into your existing class:

Homer:

```
class Homer extends Drawable // give Homer the power of the Drawable class!
{
  Homer(float x, float y)
  {
    // I can read in the code that your image will be (60, 52), but you have to write the manipulation here
    super(x, y, 60, 52, "homer.png");
    img.resize (60, 52);   
  }

  public void Update() {
    // do Update stuff so Homer can move around
  }
}
```

Notice how smaller this class is now that all the Drawable stuff is dealt elsewhere.

Now, here's for the Salad class:

First, you can drop the `salad1, salad2, salad3` global variables. We'll put them in a list, and you'll be able to have more or less of them if you want (you can think of this as being able to change the difficulty setting):

```
int numberOfSalads = 3;
ArrayList<Salad> salads = new ArrayList<Salad>();
```

In the place where you innitialize the salads, you can initialize them in a loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfSalads; i++) {
  salads.add(new Salad(random(25,475), 900, 3);
}
```

Sure, there will be some modifications to make to the Salad class, too:

```
class Salad extends Drawable {
  Salad(float x, float y, float speedY)
  {
    super(x, y, 60, 52, "salad.png");
    this.speedY = speedY; // Drawable will take it from here
    img.resize (60, 52);
  }

  protected void Move() // I knew this would come in handy!
  {
    // I have no idea what's going on, just re-writing your stuff
    y = y - speedY;
    y = y + random(-5, 5);

    if (this.y < 0)
    {
      this.y = 900; // once the salads y is less than 0 they restart at 900
      this.x = random(25, 475);
      speedY = speedY + 0.5;
    }
  }
}
```

So far, so good. There are MANY other places where you'll have to adapt the code, but you should notice that so far you've removed more lines that You've added. That's a good thing. As long as your code is easy to read, making it shorter means that there's less places to look for nasty bugs to fix.

Also, when you avoid repeating the same lines (like all those identical Render functions) by having them all in one place (the Drawable class in this case), you also avoid having to hunt down every iteration of your code if you want to make one change. This is called DRY code. DRY (for Dont Repeat Yourself) code is waaay easier to debug and maintain. As a rule of thumb, every time you copy and paste code without any change, you should ask yourself if you could just keep these line in one centralized place, whether it's a variable or a function or a class.

I'll let you code the Burger class. I think you'll manage it now that you have seen how to deal with the others.

Now, let's take a look at how to update your main loop, `draw()`:

```
void draw ()
{
  // As a general rule, all your game states should be dealt in the game loop.
  // I like 'switch' statements for this kind of operations
  // Also, try not to clutter the game loop. If you have a lot of code here, you should probably put them into functions
  // it will make it easier to read and the game loop can very easily become a spaghetti nightmare if you're not careful.
  switch(gameMode) {
  case Menu:
    // Do Menu stuff
    break;
  case Active:
    drawBackground();  // Maybe this should be before the switch, I'm not sure how you want to deal with this

    // Updates
    user1.Update();
    burger.Update();
    for (Salad s : salads) {
      s.Update();
    }

    // Check for collisions
    // I may be mistaken but I think only the Homer can collide with stuff
    if (burger.Crash(user1.x, user1.y, user1.w, user1.h)) {
      // Do burger crash stuff
    }
    for (Salad s : salads) {
      if (s.Crash(user1.x, user1.y, user1.w, user1.h)) {
        // Do Salad crash stuff
      }
    }

    // Render
    user1.Render();
    burger.Render();
    for (Salad s : salads) {
      s.Render();
    }
    break;
  case End:
    // Do End stuff
    break;
  }
}
```

This should put you on track.

If, for some reason you only want to use the intersect method: remember that the width and height of your objects are the one you use for their images.

---

You probably have questions, don't hesitate to ask away. And have fun!

Comment: Wow thats a lot of useful information to take in, I have attempted to implement the collision function you used but struggle to adapt it to my code as mine uses images so i'm not sure how to go about it. I also need to store the salads in an array which i am attempting to do

Comment: I added point 4 to give you some more help with specifics. I went into maybe more details than you wanted, but it's a useful read nonetheless. I also dealt with the collisions while I was at it, but you may want to adapt to what you're doing exactly.

Comment: So i managed to implement it all thanks to you  but i noticed that the collision detection is returning when homer is directly above either salad or burger and above it by around 100-200 pixels

Comment: That would need debugging. I cannot help without a working example, but if you zip your files and share them I'll take a look at it.

Comment: where can i share the files to

Comment: Any file transfert website will do. https://wetransfer.com/ works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210433/discussion-between-zubair-ali-and-laancelot).

Answer (score 0):

the function

```
boolean intersect(float x1, float y1, float w1, float h1, float x2, float y2, float w2, 
float h2)
{
    boolean checkX = x1 < x2 && x1+w1 > x2 || x1 < x2+w2 && x1+w1 > x2+w2 || x1 > x2 && 
x1+w1 < x2+w2 || x1 < x2 && x1+w1 > x2+w2; 
    boolean checkY = y1 < y2 && y1+h1 > y2 || y1 < y2+h2 && y1+h1 > y2+h2 || y1 > y2 && 
y1+h1 < y2+h2 || y1 < y2 && y1+h1 > y2+h2;

    return checkX && checkY;
}
```

only checks if rect1 is inside of rect2

in the function you dont neeed any `or` statements

here is the correct function

```
boolean intersect(float x1, float y1, float w1, float h1, float x2, float y2, float, w2, float h2)
{
    boolean checkX = x1 < x2+w2 && x1+w1>x2;
    boolean checkY = y1 < y2+h2 && y1+h1>y2;

    return checkX && checkY;
}
```