# "Avoid Falling Blocks " the game on Processing java

Tags: java, processing

So I am making this game in processing JAVA and the code is below so the gist is I have a ball and it avoids the falling rectangles so, for now, the ball can move sideways and the rectangles fall from above but how do I decrease my life when a rectangle hits the ball.

I made a function named Lives which was supposed to decrease lives if the circle gets hit with a rectangle but I can't come up with the code for that. Could anyone help with that?

```
int score;
int score1;
int miss;
int lives=10;
int ballx, bally;
 
class Rect
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float speed;
  float leng;
  color c;
  boolean valid;
 
  final int MAX_COLOR = 255;
  final int MIN_X = 50, MAX_X = 750;
  final int MIN_Y = -800, MAX_Y = -100;
  int MIN_SPEED = 1, MAX_SPEED = 2;
  final int MIN_Leng = 50, MAX_Leng =100 ;
 
  Rect()
  {
    initAll();
  }
 
  void initAll() {
    valid = true;
    c     = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    x     = random(MIN_X, MAX_X); 
    y     = random(MIN_Y, MAX_Y);
    speed = random(MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED);
    leng  = random(MIN_Leng, MAX_Leng);
  }
 
 
  void update() {
    if (!valid) {
      initAll();
      return;
    }
    move();
    draw_rect();
  }
  void draw_rect()
  {
    fill(c);
    rect (x, y, leng, leng);
  }
 
 
  void move()
  {
    if (y-leng <= height)
    {
      y += speed;
    } else if (y-leng > height )
    {
      valid = false;
      miss++;
    }
  }
 
  void Lives()
  {
    
  }
  void GameOver()
  {
    if (lives==0)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < Obj.length; i++)
      {
        Obj[i] = new Rect();
      }
 
      background(0);
      textSize(50 );
      fill(255);
      text( "You Lose ", 15, 150);
      text( "Score: " + score, 15, 100);
    }
  }
 
 
  boolean isOver(int mx, int my) {
    float disX = x - mx;
    float disY = y - my;
    if (sqrt(sq(disX) + sq(disY)) < leng/2 ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
 
 
Rect [] Obj = new Rect [10];
 
 
void setup() {
  size (400, 600);
  ballx=200;
  bally=300;
  for (int i = 0; i < Obj.length; i++)
  {
    Obj[i] = new Rect();
  }
}
 
 
void draw() {
  
  background(0);
  textSize(50);
  //fill(0);
  text( "Score: " + score, 0, 100);
  text("Lives: " + lives, 0, 50);
  ellipse(ballx,bally,20,20);
 
  for (int i = 0; i < Obj.length; i++) {
    Obj[i].update();
    //Obj[i].Lives();
    Obj[i].GameOver();
  }
  surface.setTitle(nf(frameRate, 3, 2));
}



void keyPressed(){
  
  for(Rect s : Obj){
    if ( key =='q' ){
     ballx=ballx-2;
     score++;
     score1++;
    s.valid = false;
     break;
    }
    if ( key =='e'){
     ballx=ballx+2;
     score++;
     score1++;
     s.valid = false;
     break;
    }
  }
      
}
```

Comment: Check the position of the rectangles and the ball everytime something moves. If the distance between ball and rectangle on both axes is too low you have a hit.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest i think think of is -

case 1 - if you want health of ball to reduce gradually :

Define maximum_Health variable and assign it to 100.
Every time a block hits your ball, reduce the health by some weight you want to define.

case 2 - if ball life is lost for every block hit

Define remaining_Lives variable and give it some value you want the number of lives to start with.
Every time a block hits your ball, reduce the remaining_Lives by one.

I think that should give you some hint.

Comment: thank you for the feedback i have declared an int lives with 10 so with every hit of it will be lives-- but i dont know how to trigger this, like what code can i run that can be in the if statment that returns that yes there was a collision pls reduce live

Comment: with every hit call your method decreaseLife and set maximum_Lives = maximum_Lives - 1. Once there are no more lives left, you can show message, pop-up, stop game etc. as per your design.

Comment: yes but how do i make the compiler know that the circle and the rectangle colided

Comment: Now you have to implement a collision detection algorithm. You can [take a look at the first point of this answer I posted a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849384/collision-detection-only-works-when-object-hits-right-in-the-centre/60859519#60859519), it'll help you with this part.